# Identify divs created programmatically in rails with coffeescript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I create a number of divs in rails that are supposed to represent the rest of the weeks of the year.  Below is my code. Notice that every div created programmatically has the class of "week" and an id equivalent to the index

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>  
  <div class="header">
    <% (1..52).each_with_index do |week, index| %>
      <div class="week" id='<%= index%>'>
        <h4><center><%= ...ruby code that generates week dates... %></center></h4>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

Now I want to use coffeescript to produce an alert with a static message whenever one of the divs programmatically created is clicked.  I have successfully paired coffeescript with other divs on my page.  I have tried something like...

```
$(".week").click ->
  alert('A div was clicked!')
```

But to no avail.  My thought is that I must identify the div by both class and id.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
   $('body').on 'click', '.week', ->
      div_id = $(this).attr('id')
      alert('A div having id = ' + div_id + 'was clicked!')
```

Comment: Thank you. I guess I should have been more assertive in my question about identifying the divs by their id as well. This works, but how could I identify the id of the div in the coffeescript?

Comment: In addition I must click 'ok' on the alert twice before the alert disappears.  This is not the behaviour I have observed with other alerts. Any thoughts?

Comment: For clicking ok twice, I guess you need to research on that :)

Comment: divOnClick was being called twice. I removed the lines: $(document).ready -> and divOnClick = -> as well as divOnClick(). Everything works now. If you agree that this is a good way to achieve this, update your code and I will accept the answer.